# uisearchbar + uitableview + nsfetchedresultscontroller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a view controller that has a UITableView which is populated by a NSFetchedResultsController.  I'd like to add a UISearchBar to be able to filter the records from Core Data that are displayed in the UITableView via the NSFetchedResultsController.

I'd like to know what the "cleanest" way to do this is, and if there is a clear example of this to be found.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution I found was to use two fecthedResultsController, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471289/how-to-filter-nsfetchedresultscontroller-coredata-with-uisearchdisplaycontroll?answertab=votes#tab-top) answer.